# What is the best practice to write units in superscript or subscript in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When plotting data with units containing superscript or subscript (e.g. cm<sup>2</sup>), what is the best way to write the string?

I have tried unicode and mathematical expressions in Matplotlib, but it looks like the style of both does not match the rest of the string. The former character looks squeezed, and the latter looks too big. How can we display it beautifully?

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting your entire expression into the formatter, so rather than just formatting the `"^2"` format the entire thing `"cm^2"`.
See the full tutorial here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/text/mathtext.html

Comment: That will make the 'cm' italic, which is not wanted. Setting the axis label font style to 'normal' does not make it normal.

Comment: If  you use "roman" font style (As per the link above) then this will remove the italics. This will give you what you require: '$\mathrm{cm^2}$'

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust the `mathtext` font by using the `rcParam` `mathtext.fontset`. The supported options are `'dejavusans'`, `'dejavuserif'`, `'cm'` (Computer modern), `'stix'`, and `'stixsans'`. You can use this to match more closely the `mathtext` to the rest of your text.

Alternatively, you can use [`LaTex`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/text/usetex.html) to perform the math display. You can enable this by setting the`rcParam` `text.usetex` to `True`, but note that the strings may need to be `raw` by preceding the string with `r`, i.e.

```py
r'$\text{cm}^2$'
```

Using `LaTex` will give you the most control, allowing you to directly adjust the size of the superscript or subscript directly via [`LaTex` font sizing](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_sizes,_families,_and_styles).

Comment: I tried using Latex, but it shows error. For example, running the example codes (https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/tex_demo.html) gave 'FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified'.

Comment: @ZhanhaoHu do you have a LaTex distribution installed (I.e. MikTek, TexLive)? How are you running the python script?

Comment: I am running the script in Jupyter Notebook on windows. I didn't particularly install LaTex packages. How could I install them?

Comment: I would install [MikTex](https://miktex.org/howto/install-miktex) following the instructions in that link. It should work with Jupyter notebook if you use the defaults. No guarantees it doesn’t require a bit more configuration though

Comment: I have installed MikTex, and tried the code provided in Matplotlib examples (https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/tex_demo.html). It shows error: dvipng was not able to process the following string:
b'\\\\textit{Velocity (\\xb0/sec)}

Comment: @ZhanhaoHu the string needs to be raw, precede it with an `r`- i.e. `r'\textit{...}'`

Comment: @ZhanhaoHu For some reason in that example all the strings are correct except that `ax.set_ylabel('\\textit{Velocity (\N{DEGREE SIGN}/sec)}', fontsize=16)` should be `ax.set_ylabel(r'\textit{Velocity ($^{\circ}$/sec)}', fontsize=16)`  in order to work consistently across latex installations

Comment: @ZhanhaoHu I’m glad to hear that, please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer so the question is marked as such for future users